# Error: Failed to query available provider packages

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

i'm trying to run AKS using terraform(version: 1.4.6) and when i'm performing "terraform init" getting an issues and below is the screen shot for ref.
if any one knows Kindly help on this.

Modules: AKS, KeyVault, Service Principal

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where is the second screenshot coming from?

Comment: @MarkoE I tried 2 ways in  variables.tf  (1 & 2nd screenshot ) separately

Comment: Please add any relevant code blocks, this is hard to reproduce using only screenshots.

Comment: https://github.com/piyushsachdeva/Terraform_AKS

Same link I'm performing

Comment: try adding something like ex: ` provider "azuread" {
 
}`  in main.tf  .   and then run terraform init --upgrade  . Do the same for each provider

Answer (score 1):

You are defining the [`required_providers` block](https://github.com/piyushsachdeva/Terraform_AKS/blob/master/versions.tf) in a wrong way. This:

```
terraform {

  required_providers {
    azuread = "~> 2.9.0"
    random  = "~> 3.1"
    azurerm = "~> 3.0.0"

  }
}
```

has to be re-written. You have to use the proper syntax as defined in the [documentation](https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/providers/requirements#requiring-providers). So this would be something like:

```
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = "~> 3.0"
    }
    azuread = {
      source  = "hashicorp/azuread"
      version = "~> 2.0"
    }
  }
}
```

You don't have to define the `random` provider like that. Running `terraform init` works as expected:

```
terraform init           
Initializing modules...

Initializing the backend...

Initializing provider plugins...
- Finding hashicorp/azuread versions matching "~> 2.0"...
- Finding hashicorp/azurerm versions matching "~> 3.0"...
- Installing hashicorp/azurerm v3.55.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azurerm v3.55.0 (signed by HashiCorp)
- Installing hashicorp/azuread v2.38.0...
- Installed hashicorp/azuread v2.38.0 (signed by HashiCorp)

Terraform has created a lock file .terraform.lock.hcl to record the provider
selections it made above. Include this file in your version control repository
so that Terraform can guarantee to make the same selections by default when
you run "terraform init" in the future.

Terraform has been successfully initialized!

You may now begin working with Terraform. Try running "terraform plan" to see
any changes that are required for your infrastructure. All Terraform commands
should now work.

If you ever set or change modules or backend configuration for Terraform,
rerun this command to reinitialize your working directory. If you forget, other
commands will detect it and remind you to do so if necessary.
```

Comment: Thanks,  i tried same as above (2nd msg) getting same issue

Comment: Where are you doing init from?

Comment: you are asking $ terraform init ? --> visual studio (cmd windows)

Comment: No, I mean where are you located in the file system when doing `terraform init`.

Comment: parent directory of the terraform code when main.tf is available

Comment: That is not possible since I tried both the code from the module and my proposed change and both work.